# Bitnami VM - Alias not working

Tags: bash, bitnami

I have a Debian 64-bit bitnami VM on virtualBox. The problem I have is that I can't get the alias to work.

I have the `~/.bashrc` like this:

```
alias php='/opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php'
alias composer='/opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php /usr/lib/plesk-9.0/composer.phar'
alias ll='ls -l'
```

I run the command pwd in order to get the right source:

```
/var/www/vhosts/<source>
```

And I have the `~/.bash_profile` like this:

```
source /var/www/vhosts/<source>/.bashrc
```

The files I have:

```
gsp@dns10366:~$ ls -l -a
total 104
drwx--x--- 13 gsp  psaserv  4096 jul 23 10:57 .
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root     4096 jun 27 09:11 ..
drwxr-xr-x 13 gsp  psacln   4096 jul 17 13:50 b2b.sap-magento
drwxr-xr-x  2 gsp  psacln   4096 jul 20 10:46 backups
-rw-------  1 gsp  psacln  13701 jul 20 14:18 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 gsp  psacln     50 jun 27 12:47 .bash_profile
-rw-r--r--  1 gsp  psacln    148 jul 17 12:36 .bashrc
drwxr-xr-x  3 gsp  psacln   4096 jul 21 08:00 .cache
drwxr-xr-x  3 gsp  psacln   4096 jul 21 08:00 .config
drwxr-xr-x  2 gsp  psacln   4096 jun 27 09:11 error_docs
-rw-r--r--  1 gsp  psacln     55 jul 20 10:18 .gitconfig
drwxr-x---  2 gsp  psaserv  4096 jun 27 09:23 httpdocs
drwxr-xr-x  3 gsp  psacln   4096 jul 21 08:00 .local
drwx------  2 gsp  root     4096 jul 23 00:57 logs
drwxr-xr-x  2 gsp  psacln   4096 jul 21 08:00 .nano
drwxr-xr-x  4 gsp  psacln   4096 jul 21 08:00 .rbenv
-rw-r--r--  1 gsp  psacln     75 jun 27 15:20 .selected_editor
drwx------  2 gsp  psacln   4096 jul 21 08:00 .ssh
-rw-------  1 gsp  psacln  15688 jul 23 10:57 .viminfo
-rw-r--r--  1 gsp  psacln     13 jun 27 12:44 .vimrc
```

I have tried setting the alias without modifying the bash files, just adding them one by one like this:

```
alias composer='/opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php /usr/lib/plesk-9.0/composer.phar'
alias npm='/opt/plesk/node/9/bin/npm'
```

Is there something missing? Thank you.

Comment: do you know what is vim? why it is tagged with `vim`?

Comment: My bad, I'll edit right now. Thank you.